# How to set different text in spinner drop-down menu and selected item?

Tags: android, spinner

Imagine I'm building a simple currency conversion app. And I have a spinner for currency selection. I only want it to show short 3-letter code of a currency (USD for dollar, EUR for euro, etc.)

For some not so widely-knwon currencies I'd like to keep long names in drop-down and hide them as soon as the item is selected. I want it to look something like this:

```
USD v    ->    USD, United States Dollar ^    ->    EUR v
               EUR, Euro

  ^                        ^                          ^
Drop-down          User clicked on spinner,      User selected EUR,
inactive,          Drop-down shown,              Drop-down inactive again,
short name         Long names shown              Short name used again
```

But what I get is:

```
USD, Uni... v    ->    USD, United States Dollar ^    ->    EUR, Eur... v
                       EUR, Euro

      ^                           ^                              ^
Drop-down inactive      User clicked on spinner,      User selected EUR,
Long name shortened     Drop-down shown,              Drop-down inactive,
with triling dots       Long names shown              Long name shortened
```

I've tried several tutorials related to ArrayAdapters but couldn't figure out if it was the right thing for me. All of them lead to showing selected item exactly the same as it was seen in drop-down. Could you, please, help me figure out how to (if possible) implement it using spinners. Or otherwise, maybe, guide me to some layout element that would be more suitable for me?

Comment: Have you tried to set your view `android:maxLines="10"` so the text does not get truncated.

Comment: @Darkman, I know about this possibility, but I actually DO want the text to be truncated to keep it shorter. I just want to be able to control how it's truncated. Keeping first 3 letters without dots in the end in this case.